# How to make an Api which can retrieve Linux system details?

Tags: python, linux, api, rest, ubuntu

I got a assignment to implement this api and I don't know where to start and I've looked with no clear results.

The closest thing I've found is using ssh to access Linux system and running commands which give me the details about the system from there. I could run a python code to run commands on local host using subprocess library. Then saw somewhere I can't run ssh using a api.

I was hoping someone could tell me where to start or how to go about this.

Thank you.

Comment: You should try using Flask. It's lightweight and easy to learn the basics to create your first API. Read the documentation so you can know how to enable an endpoint and setup quickly an application. You'll most likely be creating endpoints that use HTTP GET methods to fetch data about your Linux system.

Comment: This is the official documentation and a tutorial to quickly setup your app https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/quickstart/

Comment: If you're comfortable in JS you can set up an http/https server using NodeJS that functions as your API (very powerful, fast, and nimble).  It will accept cURL requests of any kind, however you want.  That same JS server can run any command line call that permissions allow, and pass the results back as the cURL response.  I suspect (but am not sure) a similar approach is available in python.  Happy to elaborate further.

Comment: This question is too broad for SO, I would test out some of the suggestions given and either edit your question with something more specific or delete and repost. See [Ask Wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/help/askwizard) and [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more details

Answer (score 0):

try to use a backdoor ( I would recommand using python because it's easy) with a client listening ( on your computer), to retreive information about system, do some (relatively real-time ) monitoring ( cmd typing automated !) ....., (infos processing can be done in the client side ).

here is a close example of a (keylooger backdoor ) : https://github.com/JAMAIKA-MHD/Simple-Key-Logger-with-Backdoor